# why and how to use bind() as predicate in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm given this strange-looking `std::generate()` function which create a `std::vector` of random number between a and b.

```
int myrand(int a, int b)
{
    int div = b-a;
    return a + (rand() % (b-a));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(20);
    generate( v.begin(), v.end(), bind(myrand,1, 11) );  //fill with random no. bwt 1 and 10 
    return 0;
}
```

I know how `std::generate()` function works, one has to pass a predicate into the third argument. Predicate can be in the form of:

- function
- function object
- function pointer.

But i'm quite confused by the expression `bind(myrand,1, 11)`, why do we have to write it this way?

I know that `bind` returns a function which can be placed as the third argument here.

But, isn't `myrand` a function as well? I've tried to replace the third argument with **`myrand(1,11)`** and it won't work, why is it so?

Comment: Prefer lambdas over bind they're much cheaper, e.g. `[]{ return myrand(1, 11); }` and it's much clearer for you or anyone what's going on

Comment: `std::generate` **does not** take a predicate as third parameter. It takes a generator function. A predicate is completely different.

Comment: Read a few more examples for `std::bind` use or just read the documentation. Also, as mentioned, `generate()` doesn't want a predicate: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate. A predicate is something different, used e.g. by `find()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why ... use bind()

It is generally recommended to use a lambda instead of `std::bind`.
`std::bind` is used to bind arguments to functions. 
Using `std::bind` results in a function object with a function call operator that has a smaller arity than the original function.

> How to use bind()

There is an example of how to use bind() in your question.

> one has to pass a predicate into the third argument

Actually, the third argument is a generator.

> But, isn't myrand a function as well?

Yes.

> I've tried to replace the third argument with myrand(1,11) and it won't work, why is it so?

`myrand(1,11)` is not a function (nor a function object). It is a **function call**. The result is an `int`. `int` is not a function. You are trying to pass an integer as a callable, which does not work.

Answer (score 6):

`std::bind` takes a function object, and the thing(s) you want to pass the to function object, and returns a function object that will called the supplied function object with those parameter(s).  That means

```
auto foo = bind(myrand,1, 11);
foo();
```

is the same as

```
myrand(1, 11);
```

To make life easier though, you can avoid `bind` and just use a lambda.  Doing that would give you

```
generate( v.begin(), v.end(), [](){ return myrand(1, 11); });
```

And, at least for me, this is a lot clearer that you are getting a object that will return `myrand(1, 11)` every time you call it's `operator()`.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) doesn't return a function, it returns an *object* with a function-call operator `operator()` implemented. The object is a *functor object* that can be called like a function.

When you use `myrand(1, 11)` you call the function `myrand` and pass the `int` result to `std::generate`. This `int` value can't be "called" like a function.

Answer (score 3):

Bind returns a callable. When you bind both parameters of `myrand`, then the resulting callbale will take no parameters. It can be called like

```
std::bind(myrand,1,11)();
```

When you try to pass `myrand(1,11)` that is not a callable but an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> But i'm quite confused by the expression `bind(myrand,1, 11)`, why we
>   have to write it this way?
>
> I know that `bind` returns a function which can be placed as the third
>   argument here.
>
> But, isn't `myrand` a function as well? I've tried to replace the third
>   argument with `myrand(1,11)` and it won't work, why is it so?

`myrand` is a function. `myrand(1,11)` is an `int`.

`bind` takes a function, and some arguments, and returns a function-like object.

`generate` wants a function-like thing, not an `int`.